# Query that is getting average, maximum, and minimum value of days between two dates in each year

Tags: sql, max, average, min, datediff

I have a table of boats renting:
RENTING:
- RentDate PK
- ReturnDate,
- BoatId
and other not needed here fields

I need to make a query that will return four columns:
- Year
- Average number of days of renting this year
- Maximum number of days of renting this year
- Minimum number of days of renting this year

For now i have this query:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(RentDate), 
AVG(DATEDIFF(DD, RentDate, ReturnDate))  AS AVERAGE, 
MAX(DATEDIFF(DD, RentDate, ReturnDate)) AS MAXIMUM, 
MIN(DATEDIFF(DD, RentDate, ReturnDate)) AS MINIMUM  
FROM RENTING
WHERE YEAR(RentDate) = YEAR(ReturnDate)
GROUP BY YEAR(RentDate)
```

The problem is that i am thinking about the possibility when the rent is started in the end of the year, and it is finishing in another year - RentDate Year != ReturnDate. I think this query doesn't include this posibility.

Comment: Your `Renting` table needs a composite primary key of `RentDate` and `BoatId`, not just `RentDate`. Or can you only rent out one boat per day?

Comment: I can rent many boats per day, but what is the common part of it in the query that i need? I don't get it.

Comment: Apologies I was not answering your question as posted, just commenting on the table design. If the PK is only the date field you would not be able to enter more than one row for that day; although I'm guessing your `RentDate` field contains time as well, hence you are able to insert more than one rental per day. In a normalised database you would want to have a composite key to allow more than one rental at _exactly the same time_. My comment is more an academic point about database design, but as someone who designs databases it stood out when I saw your table description :)

Answer (score 2):

> I think this query doesn't include this posibility

No, it doesn't, but it's easy to fix - just take out the `WHERE` clause you added:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(RentDate), 
AVG(DATEDIFF(DD, RentDate, ReturnDate))  AS AVERAGE, 
MAX(DATEDIFF(DD, RentDate, ReturnDate)) AS MAXIMUM, 
MIN(DATEDIFF(DD, RentDate, ReturnDate)) AS MINIMUM  
FROM RENTING
/*WHERE YEAR(RentDate) = YEAR(ReturnDate)*/
GROUP BY YEAR(RentDate)
```

`DATEDIFF` works just fine, even when the year changes.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but doesn't it make a difference in calculation if i change the last GROUP BY clause to the ReturnDate? In both cases it is taking to the calculation a timespan that could be longest and is related to end of one year and begining of the next. Correct me if i think wrong.

Comment: Well, yes if you group by YEAR(ReturnDate) you will get different results.  As it stands now, if a boat was rented on 12/31/13 and returned on 1/1/14, it would count as a 2-day rental in 2013.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean and what i don't want. Also for example if one boat was rented  on 12/15/2013 and returned in 1/10/2014 it wil count this period as the maximum  value in the 2013 or 2014 (depending on groupby clause), when it should only take the part to the end of the year, or from the begining of the year. How to achieve this?

Comment: @user2838197: Actually, if a boat was rented on 12/31/13 and returned on 1/1/14, `DATEDIFF(DD, RentDate, ReturnDate)` will give you 1 rather than 2. So my question is, should `ReturnDate` actually be included into the day count?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on D Stanley's answer you want to split any rental spanning two (or more) years, attributing part of the rental to each year.

In order to do that you need to calculate how many days of the rental fall in to each year. The easiest way I know of to do that is with a [Calendar Table](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporal-data-techniques-in-sql-/). In your case you are most interested in the year for each day of the rental.

Given a Calendar table:

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar
    ([CalendarDate] date, [CalendarYear] char(4))
```

You join your rental table to the calendar which expands each rental period in to a number of rows equal to the number of days rental. You can `COUNT` the days, grouped by year, to split the rentals by calendar year.

```
SELECT RentDate, COUNT(*) AS DayCount, CalendarYear
FROM Renting INNER JOIN Calendar ON CalendarDate >= RentDate 
  AND CalendarDate < ReturnDate
GROUP BY RentDate, CalendarYear
```

The PK `RentDate` is included to separate out each distinct rental. Otherwise you'd end up with a single figure for each year and not be able to calculate your min, max and average.

To get the aggregate values, wrap the first query in another one:

```
SELECT CalendarYear,
       AVG(DayCount) AS AVERAGE,
       MAX(DayCount) AS MAXIMUM, 
       MIN(DayCount) AS MINIMUM  
FROM (
    SELECT RentDate, COUNT(*) AS DayCount, CalendarYear
    FROM Renting INNER JOIN Calendar ON CalendarDate >= RentDate 
      AND CalendarDate < ReturnDate
    GROUP BY RentDate, CalendarYear
) AS T
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1dc5/1) so you can see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it, you need to split rentals that cover the year-end at the end of the year. I would use what I like to call Test-Driven Query Design (TDQD) to build the query in sections.

#### Rentals in a single year

This probably covers the bulk of the data:

```
SELECT YEAR(RentalDate) AS RentalYear,
       DATEDIFF(dd, RentalDate, ReturnDate) AS RentalDays
  FROM Renting
 WHERE YEAR(RentalDate) = YEAR(ReturnDate)
```

#### Rentals which span a year end

This query deals with the part of the rental in the start year:

```
SELECT YEAR(RentalDate) AS RentalYear,
       DATEDIFF(dd, RentalDate, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(RentalDate), 12, 31)) AS RentalDays
  FROM Renting
 WHERE YEAR(RentalDate) + 1 = YEAR(ReturnDate)
```

This query deals with the part of the rental in the next year:

```
SELECT YEAR(ReturnDate) AS RentalYear,
       DATEDIFF(dd, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ReturnDate), 1, 1), ReturnDate) AS RentalDays
  FROM Renting
 WHERE YEAR(RentalDate) + 1 = YEAR(ReturnDate)
```

#### Rentals that span more than two years

This is trickier still.  I'm going to point out that a single rental could, in theory, start on 2011-04-14 and end on 2014-09-30 (for sake of argument), in which case there is a part-year rental in 2011, two full year rentals in 2012 and 2013 (but one has 366 days rented and the other 365 days rented), and then a part-year rental in 2014.  But I am not going to solve that part of the problem.

#### Query without aggregates

The previous three queries need to be combined with UNION ALL to create the raw data over which aggregates should be run:

```
SELECT YEAR(RentalDate) AS RentalYear,
       DATEDIFF(dd, RentalDate, ReturnDate) AS RentalDays
  FROM Renting
 WHERE YEAR(RentalDate) = YEAR(ReturnDate)
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(RentalDate) AS RentalYear,
       DATEDIFF(dd, RentalDate, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(RentalDate), 12, 31)) AS RentalDays
  FROM Renting
 WHERE YEAR(RentalDate) + 1 = YEAR(ReturnDate)
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(ReturnDate) AS RentalYear,
       DATEDIFF(dd, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ReturnDate), 1, 1), ReturnDate) AS RentalDays
  FROM Renting
 WHERE YEAR(RentalDate) + 1 = YEAR(ReturnDate)
```

#### Aggregating the data

```
SELECT RentalYear,
       AVG(RentalDays) AS Average,
       MIN(RentalDays) AS Minimum,
       MAX(RentalDays) AS Maximum
  FROM (SELECT YEAR(RentalDate) AS RentalYear,
               DATEDIFF(dd, RentalDate, ReturnDate) AS RentalDays
          FROM Renting
         WHERE YEAR(RentalDate) = YEAR(ReturnDate)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT YEAR(RentalDate) AS RentalYear,
               DATEDIFF(dd, RentalDate, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(RentalDate), 12, 31)) AS RentalDays
          FROM Renting
         WHERE YEAR(RentalDate) + 1 = YEAR(ReturnDate)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT YEAR(ReturnDate) AS RentalYear,
               DATEDIFF(dd, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ReturnDate), 1, 1), ReturnDate) AS RentalDays
          FROM Renting
         WHERE YEAR(RentalDate) + 1 = YEAR(ReturnDate)
       ) AS Rentals
 GROUP BY RentalYear
```

Comment: Haven't checked the entire answer yet but this one part is certainly a problem: using `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(RentalDate), 12, 31)` as the ending date will result in a loss of one day. Easy to see the issue if you imagine a range that starts exactly on Dec 31: `DATEDIFF(DAY, '****1231', '****1231')` will give you `0` whereas you'd want `1`. So, for correct results, it should be replaced with `DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(RentalDate) + 1, 1, 1)`.

Comment: @AndriyM: the calculation shown in the question assumes the start and end dates are different, as it produces 0 when the start date and the end date are the same. Off-by-one's are a detail that's readily fixable — and a key part of why it should be done with TDQD (testing with data as you go). The key concept is the three-way UNION. Incidentally, ignoring year ends, a rental from New Year's Eve to New Year's Day should be 1 day according to the question — not 2 days. (But that may be a bug!) I'm off to bed now (it's at least an hour past bedtime). I'll review and fix the code later today.

Comment: Good point, I didn't realise that at first. [Asked the OP to clarify.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537711/query-that-is-getting-average-maximum-and-minimum-value-of-days-between-two-da/26542289?noredirect=1#comment41710697_26537874)

Comment: I was checking the last query but there is some problem with aggregating query here, it says me: Incorrect syntax near near the kwyword GROUP.

Comment: Oh, I didn't give the union a name…add `AS rentals` or similar.

Comment: Ok, it's great now, i don't allow a rent longer that year, so there will be no rentals that will begin in eg 2013, and end in 2015. So i think this is all what i need. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good.  Do watch for how many days a rental that starts on 2014-04-01 and ends on 2014-04-01 counts for; at the moment, it is 0 days.  You can fix that, and any other 'off-by-one' issues with minor tweaks.  Check carefully.

Comment: One question, about rentals between years. I have some rentals that begin on 31 Dec, and end on 1 Jan next year. So the rental is for one day, but i think that when we are using DATEFROMPARTS then this rental is count as 0 days, and it should count for one. When i will add +1 to both select queries that selects days from the end of year, and the days from the beggining of the year, then it will return too much days.. that's a problem i think

Comment: That's a valid concern, but it is also purely definitional — I can't answer for you what your business rules are. If someone rents on New Year's Eve and returns the item on New Year's Day, is that (a two day rental, or) a one day rental in the old year, or a one day rental in the new year? You can make a case for any of those; it is an arbitrary decision (though if you make it a two day rental, you need to be consistent and make any other rental taken out one day and returned the next into a two day rental, and a rent and return on same day counts as one day). There's not one 'right' answer.

Comment: The concern that i am considering is one day for every rental that begin in one day and is ending in the next day.

Comment: So, change the end date for a rental that starts in one year and ends in the next to 1st January instead of 31st December; that gives the extra day you seem to want.